# Custom entity not showing in Features

Tags: entities, features

I have created a custom entity - which seems to be working pretty well. I can create Bundles, build views on those bundles, create individual entities ad nauseum, I can reference the entity in entity reference fields. I can see the Views the Entity module creates in Features, I just can't see the entity or its bundles.

Even worse, the other custom entities I have written are showing just fine.

Any thoughts on what might be wonky? or steps to debug features?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's due to entities being exportable or not - but without actual source code (trimmed to minimal code needed for them to work, of course) of one not working and one or two working all right, we can't really tell you much.

Comment: well, you helped my quite a bit just with that and I thank you. turns out I was missing the exportable references. I found this: https://drupal.org/node/1021526 + some examples led me to the right place.

Comment: Oh, and it's also possible to use hook_features_api() to make an entity a feature_source. in case anyone finds this later :-)